# Django 1.5. Users attributes in comments framework

Tags: django, model, django-comments

I use MyUser model in Django 1.5 (e-mail as login):

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
 def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
       # date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(email,
        password=password,
        #date_of_birth=date_of_birth
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


 class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True,
)
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
second_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
about=models.TextField(blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name','first_name','second_name',]

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.MyUser'
```

I activated django comments framework:

settings.py:

```
'django.contrib.comments',
```

urls:

```
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

template (only authorized user can add a comment):

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2> {%  get_comment_form for post as form %} 
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post" > {% csrf_token %}   
{% if next %}
<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /></div>
{% endif %}     
{{form.content_type}}{{form.object_pk}}{{form.timestamp}}{{form.security_hash}}
Comment:<br />
{{form.comment}}       
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" /> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-post" value="Post"  />
<input type="submit" name="preview" class="submit-preview" value="Preview" />
</form> 

{% get_comment_count for post as comment_count %}   
<h2>Comments: [{{ comment_count }}]</h2> 
{% get_comment_list for post as comment_list %} 
{% for comment in comment_list|dictsortreversed:"submit_date" %}
<dl id="comments">      
{{ comment.email }} {{ comment.submit_date|date:"d.m.Y G:i" }}
<dd>
{{ comment.comment|striptags|urlizetrunc:20|linebreaksbr }}
</dd>
</dl>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get user's model fields 'first_name' and others? comment.email and comment.name gives me 'e-mail' field, comment.first_name gives me nothing. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [built-in comment model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/) documentation, you could access a user posted comment via `{{ comment.user }}` in your template. Consequently, you could access `MyUser` model fields like this `{{ comment.user.email }}` or `{{ comment.user.first_name }}`, etc.